# Не загружается ubuntu, выдает много ошибок

Tags: ubuntu

Новая ubuntu при загрузке выдает только вот это, не пуская больше никуда

[image: при загрузке выдает вот это]

Что делать?

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: Там же написано "Смотри 'systemctl статус mysql.service'". Подробности там.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по логу загрузки и Вас не может запуститься MySQL Community Server. Попробуйте перезапустить ОС в безопасном режиме. Чтобы запустить систему в безопасном режиме: во время запуска нажмите клавишу `SHIFT` или `ESC`, а далее выберите пункт `Recovery Mode`. После запуска попробуйте удалить MySQL Community Server.

Comment: Со временем и датой все в порядке, он в биосе показывает их верно. Соединение с интернетом так же в порядке.

Comment: А загружается нормально? Ну всмысле Вы можете войти в систему?

Comment: В том и дело, что совсем нет

Comment: Ubuntu с графическим интерфейсом?

Comment: @inDee Я обновил ответ. Попробуйте следовать инструкциям выше